# Is it appropriate to send and receive ipcRenderer command in same function?

Tags: electron

Is this an acceptable way to send and receive commands from the renderer process? Will the event listeners automatically get removed?

```
 await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ipcRenderer.on("command:send", resolve);
      ipcRenderer.on("command:receive",(_,err) => reject(err));
    });
```

Comment: Event listeners won't be automatically removed, you need to deregister them manually. Other than that, it's usually not a good practice to use the `Promise` constructor in general. IPC Is event based, you should not try to change it's nature.

Comment: I .. I'm not sure what you want to achieve. A typical use case is that you send a message and listen on another channel for a response. But that's not what you are doing here.